# Subtraction of elements from $\mathbb Z$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Let $M_n$ be the set of integers which are integer multiples of $n$. If $\mathbb N = {1,2,3...}$ What would

$$
\mathbb Z - \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}M_{2n+1}
$$

be?

I know that $M_{2n+1}$ represents all the odd sets of $M_n$ except $1$, would the remaining terms in $\mathbb Z$ just be the terms that are only have even prime factorizations?

Comment: You have the correct answer. Can you think of a better way to say "terms that have even prime factorizations"?

Comment: If a number has an odd divisor (greater than $1$) then it is removed. What numbers remain?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see fairly easily that $k \mid n$ implies $M_n \subset M_k$. Therefore we can only consider $M_p$ for $p$ prime (each $M_{2n+1}$ is contained in one of these). Effectively you're removing all integers that have an odd prime in their prime factorisation, so the resulting set is $\{ k \in Z : p \mid k \Leftrightarrow p =2,\, p\, \, \textrm{prime}\}$